# Get formatted attributes from a related table for eloquent model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 tables

```
 1. User table[id, name, email]
 2. user_roles[user_id, role_id]
 3. roles[ id, permission{post:{edit:true,delete:false}} ]

 user hasone user_roles

 roles belongs to user_roles
```

`userRole.role` is eager loaded in user model

Is it possible to get the permission by calling some custom function in user model.
instead of `user->userRole->role` everytime.
like call like `$user->permissions()` will return json from roles tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method in your **User** model like this-

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->userRole->role;
}
```

Laravel allows you to call your relation like that. Here **$this** represents your **User** model where you created this method. So calling a relation on **$this** would work without any problem.

Then you can call this with your user collection like this-

```
$user->permissions();
```

If you want to use this with logged in user then you can call it like this-

```
auth()->user()->permissions();
```